# How to define positive AND negative depth on taxonomy filter in views' module?

Tags: views

I am looking for a way to have an exposed filter in a view, based on the option "has taxonomy terms with depth", that can look for a term in a positive and a negative depth.

An example : I want that when "EUROPE" is selected, all contents that have "WORLD" or "SPAIN" "ENGLAND" Show-up in the results.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think i found a way to do it. 
One should create both type of filters (with positive and negative depth), and then implements a hook_form_alter this way :

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

//forbid the direct access to the filter you want to hide
$form['term_node_tid_depth_negative']['#access'] = FALSE;
//put the value of one filter in the other.
$form['term_node_tid_depth_negative']['#value'] = $form_state['input']['term_node_tid_depth_positive']; 
 }
```

And that's it !

Answer (score 0):

I've done stuff like this (eg, World and nesting of regions in the world with heirarchical taxonomies).

Take a look at [Taxonomy Edge](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge). It provides view integrations to provide search filters for `"Taxonomy edge: Parent term ID"` and I believe `"Taxonomy edge: Parent term has child term"`. I mean it adds some useful parent and child Views search filters (I dont believe it adds a single positive or negative search as you've described).